# Offine storage titles with Openlayers

Tags: openlayers, openstreetmap, offline

I'm developing an app with turn-by-turn navigation and I use OpenLayers consuming a tile server. However, I need to cache all the tiles of the route to be able to navigate offline. Is there a way to get all the tiles based on a LineString?

Currently just caching the tiles from the current position, but I need to get all the tiles in the route. I tried the following approach I found in the documentation, but as I understand it it is only caching only the seed current extent.

```js
// start seeding the cache
    function startSeeding() {
        var layer = map.baseLayer,
            zoom = map.getZoom();
        seeding = {
            zoom: zoom,
            extent: map.getExtent(),
            center: map.getCenter(),
            cacheWriteActive: cacheWrite.active,
            buffer: layer.buffer,
            layer: layer
        };
        // make sure the next setCenter triggers a load
        map.zoomTo(zoom === layer.numZoomLevels-1 ? zoom - 1 : zoom + 1);
        // turn on cache writing
        cacheWrite.activate();
        // turn off cache reading
        cacheRead1.deactivate();
        cacheRead2.deactivate();

        layer.events.register("loadend", null, seed);

        // start seeding
        map.setCenter(seeding.center, zoom);
    }

function seed() {
        var layer = seeding.layer;
        var tileWidth = layer.tileSize.w;
        var nextZoom = map.getZoom() + 1;
        var extentWidth = seeding.extent.getWidth() / map.getResolutionForZoom(nextZoom);
        // adjust the layer's buffer size so we don't have to pan
        layer.buffer = Math.ceil((extentWidth / tileWidth - map.getSize().w / tileWidth) / 2);
        map.zoomIn();
        if (nextZoom === layer.numZoomLevels-1) {
            stopSeeding();
        }
    }

    // stop seeding (when done or when cache is full)
    function stopSeeding() {
        // we're done - restore previous settings
        seeding.layer.events.unregister("loadend", null, seed);
        seeding.layer.buffer = seeding.buffer;
        map.setCenter(seeding.center, seeding.zoom);
        if (!seeding.cacheWriteActive) {
            cacheWrite.deactivate();
        }
        if (read.checked) {
            setType();
        }
        seeding = false;
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! Can you provide details as to what you have tried already?

Comment: @whyzar I added that I already tried to do it but it doesn’t completely solve the problem because it’s necessary to take the entire route